# Ruby on Rails Bootstrap popover load content from database to a form label

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, popover

I m a totally new to RoR and need some help.

I have a form on my page, and wanted to use the bootstrap popover to guide users to fill in the form. I managed to display the popover with content hard coded to a link of the form label:

```
=f.input :field_name, label: link_to("Field Name", "#", "data-toggle" => "popover", "data-content" => "testing", "data-original-title" => "Testing")
```

This causes a minor problem, when i click on the label, the page always go up to the page head.
Also, i got a lot of form fields, just wondering if i can store all the popover title & content to database, and retrieve them when users click on form labels.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

The reason it is going to the top of the page is because of the '#'. This is a tag used for anchors and that is why it is going to the top of the page.

You can either use javascript to stop this link from executing:

for example with jQuery

```
$('.link-class').click(function(e){e.preventDefault();});
```

or just use an "A" tag without an href

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But after i remove the # or href, popover won't show. And any suggestions on the database thing?